# DialogFragment use to launch TimePicker

Tags: android

I realize that you need to get a transaction going before doing the following code. How do I make that transaction a TimePickerDialog?

```
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

How would I integrate that code with this code:

```
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    mHour = hourOfDay;
                    mMinute = minute;
                }
    };
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Log.d("is it in here","");
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
        }
        return null;
```

New code below. It's giving an undefined constructor error due to the "this". How do I fix that? I know I need to pass it a context.. but how?

```
        public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        private int mHour;
        private int mMinute;
        public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
            MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("title", title);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }
        private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        mHour = hourOfDay;
                        mMinute = minute;
                    }
        };
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("is it in here","");
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                        mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
            return null;

        }
    }
```

Code edit #2:

```
        public TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    mHour = hourOfDay;
                    mMinute = minute;
                }
    };
    public void notification(String value){
        // add a click listener to the button
        //showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);

        // get the current time
        //final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        //mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        //mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    }
```

Comment: has this question been resolved??  if so, can you pick or post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/

You dont need a transaction to a timepicker,
but u can set a timepicker in an extra layout.xml, fill a fragment with this and start a new dialogfragment as u already did.

Furthermore u dont really need a fragment if u want to display a dialog.
U could use

`new TimePickerDialog.show()`

The way you did is deprecated, where dialogs are pushed through the "onCreateDialog()" of the current activity. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog(int)

Comment: That's actually with the use of showDialog() instead of DialogFragment. showDialog() is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You do it exactly the way you normally do it for an activity. The only difference is that your TimePickerDialog just will be created within a DialogFragment.

ie you need to create your DialogFragment subclass (just like a subclass of activity), put your picker and everything else in there, that's all - no magic involved :-)

Comment: Could you take a look at the updated code. I have to pass a context but don't know how... Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Actually, could you check edit #2. It seems easier but just doesn't do anything. I must be missing something small.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which edit you want answered currently, but for edit one you can replace the this like so:

```
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

My snippet, it works for both dialog and embedded display (see below how):

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Time t = new Time();
        t.setToNow();

       // Uses the current time as the default values for the picker
       Bundle args = getArguments();
       int hour = args.getInt(GLarmStrings.FRAGMENT_ARGS_TIME_PICKER_HOUR, t.hour);
       int minute = args.getInt(GLarmStrings.FRAGMENT_ARGS_TIME_PICKER_MINUTE, t.minute);

       TimePicker tp = new TimePicker(getActivity());
       tp.setIs24HourView(GLarmApp.is24HourEnabled(getActivity()));
       tp.setCurrentHour(hour);
       tp.setCurrentMinute(minute);
       tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(...)
       return tp;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Time t = new Time();
        t.setToNow();

       // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
       Bundle args = getArguments();
       int hour = args.getInt(GLarmStrings.FRAGMENT_ARGS_TIME_PICKER_HOUR, t.hour);
       int minute = args.getInt(GLarmStrings.FRAGMENT_ARGS_TIME_PICKER_MINUTE, t.minute);

       // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
       return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, GLarmApp.is24HourEnabled(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }   
}
```

To use it:

```
if (hasDialogFrame) {
    fragment.setShowsDialog(false); // maybe unnecessary
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.main_dialogs, fragment, "test").commit();  
} else {
    fragment.setShowsDialog(true); // maybe unnecessary
    fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), GUI_DIALOG_TIME_PICKER);
}
```

Comment: I apologize because it's not complete...in case of View display you might consider having an ok button (which at the moment I don't see showing in my project) or some other layout from onCreateView.